# Скриншот текущего состояния приложения

Tags: android

В приложении я отображаю возникающие ошибки путем показа текста на скриншоте экрана приложения, отображенного в сером цвете (GrayScale). Для этого я делаю скриншот так:

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View v) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    v.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}

final ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView();
Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromView(root);
```

И дальше отображаю этот `Bitmap` в оттенках серого, что собственно работает хорошо.
А проблема вот в чем: выполнение `getBitmapFromView` на некоторых устройствах (Galaxy S5 например, неожиданно) занимает 500-700 мс. И мой вопрос состоит в том, есть ли более быстрый способ сделать скриншот `View`?

**Edit:**
В моем случае долго рисовался GradientDrawable (около 450 мс.). Я оптимизировал его, и теперь все происходит за 200 мс. Но вопрос остается: Есть ли альтернативные, более быстрые способы?

Comment: Задал вопрос также на ENG SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33492680/way-to-take-screenshot-of-view-faster

Comment: А если попробовать вот так v.getDrawingCache(). Сталкивался с такой проблемой, но точно уже не могу сказать как решил.

Comment: @АндройдАндройд, `getDrawingCache()` делает именно то ,что и мой код.